# I dont know what module I'm missing

Tags: discord.js

Okay so here's my code:

```js
const mineflayer = require("mineflayer");
const discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const colors = require("colors");

const client = new discord.Client({autoReconnect: true});
const options = {
    host: 'mc.hypixel.net',
    port: 25565,
    version: '1.8.9',
    username: config["minecraft-username"],
    password: config["minecraft-password"],
};

// minecraft bot stuff vv
let mc;
(function init() {
    console.log("Logging in.");
    mc = mineflayer.createBot(options);
    mc._client.once("session", session => options.session = session);
    mc.once("end", () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Connection failed. Retrying..");
            init();
        }, 60000);
    });
}());

let uuid;
let name;
mc.on("login", () => {
    uuid = mc._client.session.selectedProfile.id;
    name = mc._client.session.selectedProfile.name;
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Sending to limbo.");
        mc.chat("/achat \u00a7c<3");
    }, 1000);
    mc.chat("/gc Logged in")
});

mc.on("message", (chatMsg) => {
    const msg = chatMsg.toString();
    console.log("Minecraft: ".brightGreen + msg);
    if (msg.endsWith(" joined the lobby!") && msg.includes("[MVP+")) {
        console.log("Sending to limbo.");
        mc.chat("/achat \u00a7ca");
        return;
    }

    if (msg.startsWith("Guild >") && msg.includes(":")) {
        let v = msg.split(" ", 2);
        if (v[2].includes(name + ":") || v[3].includes(name + ":")) return;

        let splitMsg = msg.split(" ");
        let i = msg.indexOf(":");
        let splitMsg2 = [msg.slice(0,i), msg.slice(i+1)];
        let sender, sentMsg;
        if (splitMsg[2].includes("[")) {
            sender = splitMsg[3].replace(":","");
        } else {
            sender = splitMsg[2].replace(":","");
        }
        sentMsg = splitMsg2[1];

        let embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(sender + ": " + sentMsg, "https://www.mc-heads.net/avatar/" + sender)
            .setColor("GREEN");

        //channel.send(embed);
        client.guilds.get(config["discord-guild"]).channels.get(config["discord-channel"]).send(embed);
    }
});

// discord bot stuff vv
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Discord: Logged in.".bgBlue);
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.channel.id !== config["discord-channel"] || message.author.bot || message.content.startsWith(config["discord-bot-prefix"])) return;
    console.log("Discord: ".blue + message.author.username + ": " + message.content);
    mc.chat("/gc d. " + message.author.username.replace(" ", "") + ": " + message.content);
});

client.login(config["discord-token"]);
```

And here's my package.js file:

```json
{
  "name": "discord-hypixel-bridge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Squag",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.5.1",
    "mineflayer": "^2.40.0",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "follow-redirects": "^1.13.1",
    "safe-buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "nearley": "^2.20.0"
  }
}
```

Here's the error that I get:

`Check /app/package.json: command not found. Is a start script missing?`

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are you trying to run `npm start`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `npm start` to run your project, you need to add the `scripts` object to your `package.json`. Also, your file is currently called `package.js`, so make sure to rename that to `package.json`.

```json
{
  "name": "discord-hypixel-bridge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Squag",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.5.1",
    "mineflayer": "^2.40.0",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "follow-redirects": "^1.13.1",
    "safe-buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "nearley": "^2.20.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ."
  }
}
```

More info on the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts).